# Godot request_raw returns ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: http, godot

I'm trying to upload an image to an AWS API endpoint using the HTTPClient request_raw method. I've temporarily swapped my endpoint name for [www.php.net](http://www.php.net) in the code, like in the documentation. I get the same error using my AWS endpoint.

I'm expecting to successfully POST the `headers` and `body` arguments.

I've tested all the parameters and they're the correct object types, according to the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_httpclient.html#class-httpclient-method-request-raw).

request.request_raw() returns: `request_raw: Condition "status != STATUS_CONNECTED" is true. Returned: ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

```
extends Node

func _ready():
    var request = HTTPClient.new()
    request.connect_to_host("www.php.net", 80)
    upload_file(request)

func upload_file(request: HTTPClient) -> void:
    var file_name = "export.png"
    var file = File.new()
    file.open('res://%s' % file_name, File.READ)
    var file_content = file.get_buffer(file.get_len())

    var body = PoolByteArray()
    body.append_array("\r\n--BodyBoundaryHere\r\n".to_utf8())
    body.append_array(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n" % file_name).to_utf8())
    body.append_array("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".to_utf8())
    body.append_array(file_content)
    body.append_array("\r\n--BodyBoundaryHere--\r\n".to_utf8())
    
    var headers = PoolStringArray(["Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BodyBoundaryHere"])

    var error = request.request_raw(HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, "/support", headers, body)
    if error != OK:
        push_error("An error occurred in the HTTP request.")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/79098/httprequest-or-httpclient-for-upload-file-to-server) and made a few minor tweeks to the code.

[Easy way to set up a local server for Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B42goI3parI).

```
extends Node

func _ready():
    endpoint = "http://localhost" #make sure you have a local server running or this endpoint won't work
    port = 80 #or 443, if your endpoint uses HTTPS. 80 is for HTTP
    url = "/" #this will is where specifically on your endpoint you want post your image. This configuration will send it to the root directory. 

    var file = File.new()
    file.open('res://filename.png', File.READ)
    var file_content = file.get_buffer(file.get_len())

    var body = PoolByteArray()
    body.append_array("\r\n--WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L\r\n".to_utf8())
    body.append_array("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"filename.png\"\r\n".to_utf8())
    body.append_array("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".to_utf8())
    body.append_array(file_content)
    body.append_array("\r\n--WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L--\r\n".to_utf8())

    var headers = [
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=\"WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L\""
    ]
    var http = HTTPClient.new()
    http.connect_to_host(endpoint, port, false)

    while http.get_status() == HTTPClient.STATUS_CONNECTING or http.get_status() == HTTPClient.STATUS_RESOLVING:
        http.poll()
        OS.delay_msec(500)

    assert(http.get_status() == HTTPClient.STATUS_CONNECTED) # Could not connect

    var err = http.request_raw(HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, url, headers, body)

    assert(err == OK) # Make sure all is OK.

    while http.get_status() == HTTPClient.STATUS_REQUESTING:
        # Keep polling for as long as the request is being processed.
        http.poll()
        if not OS.has_feature("web"):
            OS.delay_msec(500)
        else:
            yield(Engine.get_main_loop(), "idle_frame")
```